# jquery .each() only doing last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having problems with this function not running correctly... it only makes the last Element have the box appear.

NOTES: `<aside>` is position: fixed; and I do know this is not a "Proper" use of `<article>` tags, but it helps me to differentiate them for now.

HTML:

```
    <aside class="character">
        <div class="personHolder">
            <div class="person"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow_box"></div>
    </aside>
    <main class="main">
        <section class="sections" id="Home">
            <article class="article1">
                <h1 class="sectionHeaders">Home</h1>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="sections" id="About">
            <article class="article2">                
                <h1 class="sectionHeaders">About Me</h1>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="sections" id="Projects">
            <article class="article3">                
                <h1 class="sectionHeaders">Projects</h1>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="sections" id="Contact">
            <article class="article3">                
                 <h1 class="sectionHeaders">Contact Me</h1>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
function checkElement() {
    var article1 = $(".article1");
    var article2 = $(".article2");
    var article3 = $(".article3");
    var article4 = $(".article4");
    var arrowTop = 170;
    var arrowBottom = 258;

    var articles = [article1, article2, article3, article4];

    $.each(articles, function(index, value) {
        if(value.offset().top < arrowTop && 
           value.offset().top + value.height() > arrowBottom) {
            $(".arrow_box").show();
        } else {
            $(".arrow_box").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

The following is the best thing I can do to a Fiddle, as I cannot make the fiddle work correctly... (Sorry)
[Free Website Host](http://portfoliotesting.herobo.com/)

I have tried the below before as well.

```
$("article").each(function() {
    if(this.offset().top < arrowTop && 
       this.offset().top + 
       this.height() > arrowBottom) {
        $(".arrow_box").show();
    } else {
        $(".arrow_box").hide();
    }
});
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
var showing = false;
$("article").each(function() {
    if (showing) return;
    if($(this).offset().top < arrowTop && 
       $(this).offset().top + 
       $(this).height() > arrowBottom) {
        $(".arrow_box").show();
        showing = true;
    } else {
        $(".arrow_box").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using _classes_ for the different articles? Are there more than one of each type? or should you be using the _id_ attribute?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Could you setup fiddle? Also, you don't have to store HTML elements to array, you can iterate through them with another each(): http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Sorry, I added more to it, to hopefully make it make more sense.

Comment: @David They are each articles, I just did this as I was running out of ideas... I have also tried the last code snippet as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are saying that each article has its own arrow box.
In your function, you will check the offset of all articles, but the `$(".arrow_box")` selector will be the same for all articles, so you will hide/show it only depending on the last articles offset.

I dont know your HTML tree, but try to change the selector to something like

```
value.closest(".arrow_box").show();
```

**Update**

You want to cancel the each() once you have found an article in range. This can be done like this for instance:

```
var showing = false;
$("article").each(function() {
    if (showing) return;
    if(this.offset().top < arrowTop && 
       this.offset().top + 
       this.height() > arrowBottom) {
        $(".arrow_box").show();
        showing = true;
    } else {
        $(".arrow_box").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: But the javascript you run will only show/hide the arrow_box depending on the last article, since the last article position will override the show/hides that was made on the three first articles. Maybe you can specify more what you want it to do?

Comment: Each time an article comes into the certain range...I want the $(".arrow_box") div to appear and disappear when no article is in that place.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. Then you need to trigger the evaluation of your javascript to run when user scrolls or similar. I will update my post with some code.

Comment: It is inside a whilescrolling option... ( I'm using a jQuery plugin scrollbar, http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ , for the scrolling) calling this function while it scrolls.

Comment: The link in the original question can show you what I'm doing. Each blue chunk is an article.

Comment: I see. You still got the problem that your each() function overrides the potential show that is created for the first three articles. As soon as you see an article that is in correct position, you should cancel the loop. Otherwise, the other articles will evaluate and hide the box again.

Comment: THIS WORKED!! Thank you! Only thing I needed to do was...

instead of this I needed $(this)

Thanks again!